# WordPress Custom Type Posts next previous join table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working in WordPress and I need to display the next and previous links on a custom type posts.

I need to list all the custom post types on `post_town` which is in a table

**cus_builders**

```
ID     post_town    post_type 
-----------------------------------

123    Manchester   cus_builders
```

The below code gives me all custom posts cus_builders, and I only want the builders in Manchester.

```
// get_posts in same custom taxonomy
$postlist_args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'cus_builders',
'post_town' => 'Manchester' 
);
$postlist = get_posts( $postlist_args );
```

How to join the query on table `cus_builders` so it only gives me back based on `cus_builder.post_town`?

Comment: Few questions: What's the user input for your query? Do you have a post town given by the user and want to find all the matching post types from your external  `cus_builders` table? You're using a secondary query here, can you instead use the main query modified with `pre_get_posts`? Then you could easily use the `{next,prev}_posts_link` with the correct main query `$paged` value.   Ps: In general it's a good rule to avoid capital letters in slugs.

Comment: Did you added a new column (`post_town`) to the `posts` table or is `post_town` a _taxonomy_ or _custom_field_?

Comment: Ervald, post_town is in the cus_builders table.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're after, but here are two guesses:

### 1) If the user input is `$post_town`:

```
// Input:
$post_town = 'Manchester'; 

// Query:
$postlist_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => get_post_type_by_town( $post_town ),
    'tax_query'      => array(
         array( 
             'taxonomy' => 'post_town',
             'terms'    => sanitize_key( $post_town ),
             'field'    => 'slug',
         ),
    ),
);
$postlist = get_posts( $postlist_args );
```

where

```
function get_post_type_by_town( $post_town )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT post_type FROM cus_builders WHERE post_town = '%s'";
    return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post_town ) );
}
```

This setup would require multiple custom post types, sharing the same custom taxonomy `post_town`.

### 2) If the user input is `$post_type`:

```
// Input:
$post_type = 'cus_builders'; 

// Query:
$postlist_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'tax_query'      => array(
         array( 
             'taxonomy' => 'post_town',
             'terms'    => get_post_towns_by_post_type( $post_type ),
             'field'    => 'slug',
         ),
    )
);
$postlist = get_posts( $postlist_args );
```

where:

```
function get_post_towns_by_post_type( $post_type )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT post_town FROM cus_builders WHERE post_type = '%s'";
    return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $post_type ) );
}
```

This setup requires a custom taxonomy `post_town`.

---

It's in general a good idea to avoid capitals, spaces and special characters when working with slugs.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I have tried the 2 ways but still no results.  Basically I am using wpgeodirectory plugin and need to loop through listings.  The current default method with the plugin loops through all restaurants but if the user is looking at builders Manchester I only want the Next | Prev to list "Builders in Manchester" and not currently ALL builders.

Comment: The code at the moment grabs ALL builders and I only need the builders in the Town there are searching.  There is no user input, its set via URL e.g. /builders/manchester/